# Get a xml file from sdcard to android app?

Tags: android, xml, save, sd-card

I need to save a xml file from sdcard to my android app, in res/values. How can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you should explain why or what you want to achieve here - I don't think what you are asking is exactly possible. The res/values location only really exists on your development machine and is a more abstracted part of the application after compilation.

Comment: I have a xml file on sdcard...can I take the infromation from xml direct from sdcard?

Comment: you can save your xml file in data/data/packagename/file directory. and I think you cant store xml file in res/values directory. If you want to do that then I will guide you. And clarify what is your intention.

Comment: my xml file is saved in mnt/sdcard. Can you guide me?

Comment: what do you want after save it in res/values dir? will you use it as any resurce file for application? or just want to grab the data from it?

Comment: I want to save xml file in res/values directory if it is possible...otherwise, I want to know how can I acces information from the xml stored on sdcard.

Comment: I saved the content of a link in a xml file on sdcard, and now I want to use this content in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the java file command for your xml file on sdcard.

```
File file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/example.xml");
```

and using DOM or SAX parser you can parse the data(information) from it for your application.

Thnx.

EDIT: [parsing local xml file using Sax in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728064/parsing-local-xml-file-using-sax-in-android), [Read XML Resources in Android, using XmlResourceParser: XML parsing interface](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html)  or [Here](http://androidforums.com/application-development/34284-how-read-xml-file-sdcard-parse.html) or [Here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser) Look at these tutorials.

Comment: if you found this answer is correct then make correct mark and upvote it for other user. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

They are just folders in an Android project when you develop. When the app is compiled, everything in `src` and `res` is turned into binary code, and packed in one apk. Therefore I don't think that you will have `res` folder or anything like that in the device.