# SAXParser working example for Android

Tags: android

I am trying to learn SAXParser example which is working properly with Android development environment.
can any one help how to do SAXParser in Android application 
Code snippet will be good.

Thanks
Mansingh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728064/parsing-local-xml-file-using-sax-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is SAX parsing [example](http://as400samplecode.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-parse-xml-file-example-using.html). Remember based on your xml you need to change `ItemMaster` class and parsing logic.

Comment: The link is broken I guess... At least it didn't load in 1 min.